# Query failed to execute: misuse of aggregate: min()

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why do I get an error?

```
select title, mx-mn 
from (select title, Rating.mID, max(stars) as mx, min(stars) as mn from Movie, Rating 
where Movie.mID = Rating.mID 
group by mx-mn, title)
```

I need to sort by rating spread (max-min), then by title

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY clause is the same as `GROUP BY max(starts)-min(stars)`.

`max()` and `min()` return that largest/smallest value in the group. However, the expression in the GROUP BY clause is used to determine how to group the rows in the first place – it is not yet possible to compute aggregates over a group that does not yet exist.

---

Anyway, to sort rows, you need to use ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY.
But the GROUP BY is still needed to get one row for each movie:

```
SELECT title,
       max(stars) - min(stars) AS spread
FROM Movie
JOIN Rating USING (mID)
GROUP BY mID
ORDER BY spread ASC, title;
```

Comment: I put group by clause out of parentheses: select title, mx-mn 
from (select title, Rating.mID, max(stars) as mx, min(stars) as mn from Movie, Rating 
where Movie.mID = Rating.mID )
group by mx-mn, title    But it does not give the correct answer

Comment: That is not what you asked for. If that is what you actually want, edit your question to describe what you want, and show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You shoukd change the group by this way (don'use the parent query alias )

```
select title, mx-mn 
from (select title, Rating.mID, max(stars) as mx, min(stars) as mn from Movie, Rating 
where Movie.mID = Rating.mID 
group by title, Rating.mID)
```

Comment: I need to sort them by spread (max rating- min rating), then by title